# Save list of Arabic strings in database

Tags: sql-server, list, c#-2.0

I have a c# program. I have list of string. The elements of that list in Arabic. When I try to save the elements of list in database I see symbols "??????"
Here my code

```
 List<string> _names = new List<string>()
        {
            "ذهب",
            "قال",
            "تعال",
            "متى",
            "البرمجة",
            "احمد"
        };
       SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Server=DESKTOP-JRS3DQ4; DataBase=Library_DB; Integrated Security=true");
        connection.Open();
        for (int index = 0; index < _names.Count; index++)
        {
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tbl_names (id,name) VALUES ('" + index + "', '" + _names[index] + "')", connection);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        connection.Close();
```

How I can solve this problem please?

Comment: Use an `nvarchar`, not a `varchar`.

Comment: Are you mean the column type must be nvarchar? I do that but the problem is not solved

Comment: Can you try with `N ' " + _names[index] + " '` to tell sql that you want to save unicode values

Comment: Admir I try that solution but the problem is not solved.

Comment: The first problem here is you are declaring your literal string an a `varchar`(`'???' = 'ذهب' != N'ذهب'`). The **bigger** problem is your query isn't parametrised and thus open to injection. Parametrise your query and you fix both problems.

Comment: how I can fix my code?

Comment: Use a parameterised query. [SqlCommand.Parameters Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, your problem is coming from inserting strings (as varchar) instead of NVarchar.

Your code will work more-reliably, safer & faster if you define a parameterized query and parameters before you run your loop:

```
List<string> _names = new List<string>()
{
    "ذهب",
    "قال",
    "تعال",
    "متى",
    "البرمجة",
    "احمد"
};
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Server=DESKTOP-JRS3DQ4; DataBase=Library_DB; Integrated Security=true");
connection.Open();

SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tbl_names (id,name) VALUES (@Id, @Name)", connection);
command.Parameters.Add("@Id", SqlDbType.Int);
command.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20); //size and type must match your DB

for (int index = 0; index < _names.Count; index++)
{
    command.Parameters["@Id"].Value = index;
    command.Parameters["@Name"].Value = _names[index];
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
connection.Close();
```

One last note: This will not help unless your DB has the `Name` column defined as a NVarChar.