# Save Arabic data of datagridview in database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database-design

I have datagridview that contain two columns (name, age). The data of that gridview in Arabic. (((Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a Int32.)))
Her my code

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Server=addie; DataBase=Library_DB; Integrated Security=true");
       connection.Open();
       SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO names (name,age) VALUES (@Name, @Age)", connection);
       command.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.Int);
       command.Parameters.Add("@Age", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50); //size and type must match your DB

       for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
       {
           command.Parameters["@Name"].Value = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value;
           command.Parameters["@Age"].Value = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].ValueType;
           command.ExecuteNonQuery();
       }
       connection.Close();
       dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
```

When I try to run the code, the following error appears

> Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a Int32.

How can I fix my code?

Comment: Please post your table definition.

Comment: Database collation is?

Comment: Google search first result http://www.sqlerudition.com/how-to-store-non-english-unicode-characters-hindi-czech-arabic-etc-in-sql-server/

Comment: You should research databinding - there is no need to fish data out of a DGV to save it.  And always use SQL parameters.

Comment: Before you write another line of code you need to read about, understand and start using parameterized queries. My friend [bobby tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) loves code like this. And since these are Arabic characters you need to make sure you are using nvarchar. Then when this is parameterized it will be simple.

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of your other question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54791572/save-list-of-string-in-database-using-c-sharp

Comment: @Dale Burrell On the contrary, I benefited a lot from the site StackOverflow and most of the answers are satisfactory to me, but I am new in the site did not know that I must show my admiration of the satisfactory answers to me. Thank you for alerting me

Comment: @AfraArif a lot of people benefit from StackOverflow.  I don't think Dale was trying to slight.   Marking a post as the answer helps not only you but all those searching for the same sort of answer.  Courtesy. :)

Comment: So now that you fixed your code and are using parameters are you still getting errors?

Comment: @Sean Lange The data type of column age is int so when I try to save the data of gridview the error I have shown appears above

Comment: Well...look closely at your code. You are setting the value of the Age parameter to the ValueType of the column.

Comment: Are you mean I must replace value type with value?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I mean. And look closely at the datatypes of your parameters. Name is an int and Age is a varchar. Of course I would urge you not to store age. You should instead store birthdate and calculate age. The value for age is stale as soon you insert the row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi if i understand your wall i think you have a typed mistake in your .net code try this :

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Server=addie; DataBase=Library_DB; Integrated Security=true");
       connection.Open();
       SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO names (name,age) VALUES (@Name, @Age)", connection);
       command.Parameters.Add("@Age", SqlDbType.Int);
       command.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50); //size and type must match your DB

       for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
       {
           command.Parameters["@Name"].Value = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value;
           command.Parameters["@Age"].Value = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].ValueType;
           command.ExecuteNonQuery();
       }
       connection.Close();
       dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
```

You have swip name type and age type.

Otherwise if it’s doesn’t work we have too know your database collation version and some other information.